# How to compute the mass flow rate for a turboprop at cruise given the static sea level value?

Tags: engine-design, turboprop, cruise

I am trying to obtain the mass flow rate of the Allison T56-A-15 used on the C130H at cruising altitude (so as to solve the Joule-Brayton cycle at cruising altitude). I know from "Turboshaft, Turboprop and Propfan: database Handbook" that the mass flow rate is 14.7 kg/s at static sea level (not sure about the meaning of this). In order to compute the mass flow rate at cruising altitude, what should I do? I've tried writing $\dot{m} = \rho A_{in} v_{TAS}$ but in this way I obtain a value of mass flow rate that I consider excessive. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I have changed the title to match the problem you're solving. Please check the edit and see if other improvements can be made.

Comment: Mass flow is determined by the thrust.

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to calculate is an off-design operating condition based on a known reference point (Sea Level Static performance, which is usually off-take performance).

You cannot simply do this by hand, this requires a model for the engine and knowledge of the off-design characteristics of the engine (map characteristics, e.g. [compressor map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressor_map)), furthermore you need the cruise power specification.